# XSS using User Agent, Possible?

Tags: web-application, xss

Is it possible in a Real world scenario to exploit this type of XSS, I'm injecting the payload in the User agent header and it is executed on it's response page. Can I craft this request such that the victim gets the changed User agent header with the request?

Comment: It would have to be stored, not reflected, if you want to exploit someone other than yourself.